# Disable JS formating in Script Tag Notepad++

Tags: javascript, html, ember.js, handlebars.js, notepad++

In Notepad++, when using Ember (and Handlebars), HTML is written inside `<script>` -

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
//Code 
</script>
```

The coloring appears to be weird - class as attribute gets highlighted as inside a `.js` file, and tags are shown sometimes in black, sometimes in blue (like they should be) and I am yet to figure out why.

Is it possible to turn off coloring just inside the `<script>` tags?

Edit: JS formatting persists up until the very first closing tag -

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span3">
            <table class="table">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>//This tag and above are black
                            Recent Posts
                        </th>//This tag and below are blue
                    </tr>
//.....
</script>
```

Comment: Not the answer of this question but why don't you go for Sublime Text?

Comment: I am used to Notepad. Tried Sublime sometime ago - was somewhat hard. So no, not really =)

Comment: You need to find a plugin that will add support for handlebars. From the looks of it you aren't using the [ember-cli](http://www.ember-cli.com/)

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but when I ran into this problem, I just started putting my templates in separate files and pre-compiling them. Now might be a good time to do that rather than try to find out how to fix this in Notepad++.

Comment: To further GJK's point, start using Ember CLI and you won't have to worry about setting up a precompilation pipeline.

Comment: Why don't you try SynWrite app? It has nested lexers, e.g. JS inside HTML. Guys may help you at forum.

Comment: Not sure if this is the proper way to do it, but based on the recent edit to the question, I added an empty closing tag </> after the initial <script... tag  but before the html tags and it worked fine.